# Error Raising COM Event With Office 2016 64 bit on Windows 8 and Windows 10

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop, excel-2016

I get an error when trying to process events raised from a multi-threaded C# dll in Office 2016 64 bit on Windows 8 or 10. It works with Office 2013 for both 32 and 64 bit versions. It works with Office 16 64 bit on Server 2008 and Server 2012 R2. The error is Run-time error ‘-2146232829 (80131603)’ Object does not match target type.

The stack trace is:

at System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[] byrefModifiers, Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters)

at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)

at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)

at COMTest.ICounterEvents.CounterProgressed(Object sender, CounterProgressedEventArgs e)
   at COMTest.Counter.IncrementCounter()

The c# code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace COMTest
{
    [ComVisible(true), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual), Guid("1912B8CF-0B0A-4F9D-A76D-5C10D6B85548")]
    public interface ICounter
    {
        void Progress();

        int Count { get; }
    }

    [ComVisible(true), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual), Guid("5150CD23-DF7A-4FBE-838A-7AFEA84A0CFC")]
    public interface ICounterProgressedEventArgs
    {
        int Progress { get; }
    }

    [ComVisible(true), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class CounterProgressedEventArgs : EventArgs, ICounterProgressedEventArgs
    {
        public int Progress { get; internal set; }
    }

    [ComVisible(true), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch), Guid("1698856D-AFDA-4C94-B6B4-5EA94958B40D")]
    public interface ICounterEvents
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        void CounterProgressed(object sender, CounterProgressedEventArgs e);
    }

    [ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(ICounterEvents))]
    [ComVisible(true), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [Serializable]
    public sealed class Counter : ICounter
    {
        public event CounterProgressedEventHandler CounterProgressed;
        public delegate void CounterProgressedEventHandler(object sender, CounterProgressedEventArgs e);

        public int Count { get; private set; }

        public void Progress()
        {
            if (CounterProgressed != null)
            {
                RunTasks(5);
            }
        }

        private void RunTasks(int threads)
        {
            var tasks = new Dictionary<int, Action>();

            var asyncResults = new IAsyncResult[threads];

            for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
            {

                tasks.Add(i, IncrementCounter);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
            {              
                var task = tasks[i];
                asyncResults[i] = task.BeginInvoke(null, null);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
            {
                var task = tasks[i];
                task.EndInvoke(asyncResults[i]);
            }
        }

        private void IncrementCounter()
        {
            if (CounterProgressed != null)
            {
                Count++;
                CounterProgressed(this, new CounterProgressedEventArgs { Progress = Count });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I ran tlbexp to generate the type library.

I ran regasm /codebase to register the dll.

I created `Class1` in Excel as follows:

```
Public WithEvents comCounter As Counter

Public Sum As Long

Public Sub Test()
    Set comCounter = New Counter
    comCounter.progress
End Sub

Private Sub comCounter_CounterProgressed(ByVal sender As Variant, ByVal e As COMTest.ICounterProgressedEventArgs)
    Sum = Sum + e.progress
    Range("A1").Value = Sum
End Sub
```

I called `Class1` using the following macro:

```
Public Sub Run()
    Dim c As Class1
    Set c = New Class1
    c.Test
End Sub
```

When executed the macro should display 15 in cell A1 but the ‘Object does not match target type’ exception is thrown.

Comment: When I use the VBA IDE to auto-create (Excel 2007) the `comCounter_CounterProgressed` method the signature is `Private Sub comCounter_CounterProgressed(ByVal sender As Variant, ByVal e As COMTest.ICounterProgressedEventArgs)`.  I would think that the interface is the proper way to marshal the COM type.  It is worth a try at least.

Comment: You did not document the Regasm.exe command you used.  My crystal ball says that you forgot the /tlb option.  Required since the interface call needs to be marshalled from the worker thread to the STA thread that executes the VBA code.

Comment: @TnTinMn I've edited the Class1 code to use the IDE generated signature. However, the same error occurs. I haven't tested it in versions of Excel prior to Excel 2013 but I suspect the code will run without error in earlier versions as there is no error in Excel 2013.

Comment: @HansPassant I've edited the question to include the /codebase option I used with regasm. As I've run tlbexp there is no need to run regasm with the /tlb option, they both create a type library. I've tested it with both ways of creating the type library and both fail.